# How to get items from string in java android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, integer

Iam developing an online booking android app. i have a little issue to get the data from the response i am getting from database. my Json object response is like this example:
"Sat": "1300-1320:1,1325-1345:5,1350-1410:9,1415-1435:1...,

in the above 1300-1320 is time slot, it is actually 13:00 to 13:20 and 1 is number of available tickets.

I need the items on list view be like this:

13:00 to 13:20

### The available tickets are 1

13:25 to 13:45

### The available tickets are 5

13:50 to 14:10

### The available tickets are 9

and ... You can get the idea. The problem is i don't know how to achieve this.

Can you please help me. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: the Sat key returns a String which is separated by comma's. So you Split the String by comma and then each one of the Splitted with the : and it will give you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick Sample how ti would look:

```
    private void parseString() {
      String data = "1300-1320:1,1325-1345:5,1350-1410:9,1415-1435:1";

      String[] commaStrings = data.split(",");
      for (String commaString : commaStrings) {
          String[] hours = commaString.split(":");
          String[] times = hours[0].split("-");

          String t1 = padded(times[0], 2, ":");
          String t2 = padded(times[1], 2, ":");
          String hour = t1 + " to " + t2;
          System.out.println("Hour: " + hour + " available: " + hours[1]);
      }
    }

    private String padded(String original, int charLimit, String separator) {
      StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();

      for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
         if (i % charLimit == 0 && i > 0) {
            formatted.append(separator);
         }
         formatted.append(original.substring(i, i + 1));
      }

      return formatted.toString();
   }
```

and the result:

```
Hour: 13:00 to 13:20 available: 1
Hour: 13:25 to 13:45 available: 5
Hour: 13:50 to 14:10 available: 9
Hour: 14:15 to 14:35 available: 1
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank u So much Kostas Drak ... This means a lot to me. I am new to java & thank u for helping.... This is great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the format of your response is going to be consistent, you can solve the problem by splitting.

Here is how :) :

```
String response = //your response ;
String[] items = response.split(",");

for(String item : items){
   String available_tickets = item.split(":")[1];
   String time_interval = item.split(":")[0];

   String from = time_interval.split("-")[0];
   String to = time_interval.split("-")[1];
   from = new StringBuilder(from).insert(from.length()-2, ":").toString();
   to = new StringBuilder(to).insert(to.length()-2, ":").toString();

   System.out.println(from + " to " + to + "\n");
   System.out.println("The available" + (available_tickets.equals("1") ? " 
   ticket is " : " tickets are ") + available_tickets);
}
```

Comment: Thank u So much for your great help... I hope to return your favor some day... Thank u...

Comment: You are welcome Arsalan Zahedi Rad. Kindly mark my answer as accepted or give it an upvote at least to show appreciation. Thanks :)